# Email containing links that redirect to a blacklisted domain

Tags: .htaccess, email, redirect

I have a tricky question that i was not able to answer.

I'm running a (perfectly legal) mass marketing campaign via email for a customer.
My customer's domain name has been blacklisted (on uribl).
let's call that "customerdomain.com"

The mails that i send contain links that perform 301 redirects to my customer domain.
let's call my domain "trackingdomain.com"
So simply put, i have emails containing links to trackingdomain.com which has a perfect reputation that redirect (http 301) to customerdomain.com (which is blacklisted)

The question is : can my email campaign be blocked or marked as spam because it's redirecting (through 301) to a blacklisted domain ?
Needless to say that the emails i'm sending are as good as we can make them.
I'm really scared about getting my rep destroyed because of my customer's bad reputation.

Thanks

Comment: If you are worried don't do it. If one customer is worth you being blacklisted too, then go ahead otherwise I'd send them elsewhere. They were blacklisted for a reason. Now they're trying to use someone else to get through. You might want to rethink that.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simply - yes, emails going to be most likely spam filtered. That's called for "spamvertising". And your domain can get blacklisted as well. Here is something to read about such cases http://blog.mailchimp.com/is-your-own-domain-name-getting-you-blocked/